# Stay a certain time on a website with the Python reqeuest method

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'd like to stay with a Python request a certain time on a webpage, is there any way how to accomplish that in Python 3.6?

I have already a working function which requests a website, so the only thing I need is a way to stay on this website for a certain time, like if you would with your real browser on this website.

Ty in advance

Comment: can you elaborate, what do you mean "stay"?

Comment: when you are on a website, which uses google analytics, it measures the time you spend on this website, so i want to simulate with a request this amount of time.

Comment: include this description in your original question by editing.